# build exist-db web application rapidly

Tags: exist-db

I am really appreciate you to lead me how to build exist-db applications with bootstrap style?

in stackoverflow there are many question about building web application with java, .Net .... 
but no one talk about exist-db

I do not care about positive or negative evaluation, please help me with answers.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you build an application with eXide (Application > New Application), Bootstrap is included. Otherwise see http://markmail.org/thread/jqbknswl52f7erna.